# Reference request for subjective/objective logic for mathematicians

Tags: logic, reference-request, category-theory, philosophy

I am self-learning William Lawvere's *Conceptual Mathematics* and *Sets For Mathematics*. He mentioned **subjective and objective logic**. I really don't understand it. Do I have to read Hegel's to fully grasp these two books?  See this [link](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/objective+and+subjective+logic).

Besides, William Lawvere said in his [Categories of space and quantity](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/William+Lawvere#Lawvere92):

> It is my belief that in the next decade and in the next century the technical advances forged by category theorists will be of value to dialectical philosophy, lending precise form with disputable mathematical models to ancient philosophical distinctions such as general vs. particular, objective vs. subjective, being vs. becoming, space vs. quantity, equality vs. difference, quantitative vs. qualitative etc. In turn the explicit attention by mathematicians to such philosophical questions is necessary to achieve the goal of making mathematics (and hence other sciences) more widely learnable and useable. **Of course this will require that philosophers learn mathematics and that mathematicians learn philosophy.**

Is there any good introductory logic(or philosophical) book covering these aspects(**subjective and objective logic**) for math students?

Comment: I suppose if you believe Lawvere then any introduction to category theory is an introduction to objective logic while any introduction to “logic” is an introduction to subjective logic. Otherwise, no, nor any good introductory book for anybody, I wouldn’t think. Philosophy is usually studied from primary sources rather than textbooks. Besides, Lawvere is not in wide company among mathematicians in his interest in Hegel (which isn’t to say his positions are wrong.)

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357569/can-you-explain-lawveres-work-on-hegel-to-someone-who-knows-basic-category-theo)

Comment: And see Andrei Rodin, [CATEGORICAL LOGIC AND HEGELIAN DIALECTICS](http://philomatica.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/dialectics.pdf)

Comment: @KevinArlin So maybe it is too dangerous for a beginner like me to immerse myself into these logical things right now. Just to live with it, feel it, and look back on it when I learn more math is a good idea?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks, they are really good material. It will take a long time to digest.

Comment: @Beginner My impression is that the nLab page on categorical formalization of Hegel's Science and Logic will be very hard going for anybody not already pretty familiar with higher topos theory, but maybe Rodin's work is more approachable.

Answer (score 1):

Objective logic is the logic intrinsic to a universe of discourse (category).  As such, the objective logic of a category can be calculated from the abstract essence(s) in which every object of the category partakes (e.g. singleton set is the abstract essence of the category of sets (in the sense of Isbell's adequacy; http://at.yorku.ca/t/o/p/d/65.htm).  The following refs may speak to your question:

[Objective Logic of Consciousness](https://philpapers.org/rec/POSOLO)

[Tools for the Advancement of Objective Logic](https://zenodo.org/record/7059109#.YzyHDXZBzIU)

[Structure and Logic of Conceptual Mind](https://philpapers.org/archive/POSSAL.pdf)

[Subobject Classifier Algorithm](https://conceptualmathematics.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/subobject-classifier-algorithm/)

[Truth and the Terminal Object](https://conceptualmathematics.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/truth-and-the-terminal-object/)